# rails 7 test fails for name-spaced controllers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing

Folder structure for controller

```bash
controllers
    api
       v1
         users_controller.rb
```

Routes file

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end 
  end
  #resources :users
  # Define your application routes per the DSL in https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

  # Defines the root path route ("/")
  # root "articles#index"
end
```

Test file

```
require "test_helper"

class UsersControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  setup do
    @user = users(:one)
  end

  test "should get index" do
    get users_url, as: :json
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should create user" do
    assert_difference("User.count") do
      post users_url, params: { user: { first_name: "test1", last_name: "test", email: "test@test.com", password: "test12345", is_active: true } }, as: :json
    end

    assert_response :created
  end

  test "should show user" do
    get user_url(@user), as: :json
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should update user" do
    patch user_url(@user), params: { user: {  user: { first_name: "test1", last_name: "test", email: "test@test.com", password: "test12345", is_active: true }  } }, as: :json
    assert_response :success
  end

  test "should destroy user" do
    assert_difference("User.count", -1) do
      delete user_url(@user), as: :json
    end

    assert_response :no_content
  end
end
```

output of `rails test`

```
Running 5 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 52765

# Running:

E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_destroy_user:
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x0000000128b89c68>
Did you mean?  users
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:33:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:32:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:31

E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_update_user:
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x000000012951ddd8>
Did you mean?  users
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:27:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:26

E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_show_user:
NoMethodError: undefined method `user_url' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x00000001295f7e48>
Did you mean?  users
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:22:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:21

E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_get_index:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `users_url' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x000000012963dc68>
Did you mean?  users
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:9:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:8

E

Error:
UsersControllerTest#test_should_create_user:
NameError: undefined local variable or method `users_url' for #<UsersControllerTest:0x00000001296771c0>
Did you mean?  users
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:15:in `block (2 levels) in <class:UsersControllerTest>'
    test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:14:in `block in <class:UsersControllerTest>'


rails test test/controllers/users_controller_test.rb:13



Finished in 0.090735s, 55.1055 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.
5 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 5 errors, 0 skips
```

Also the `users.yml` is filled up with correct data as well. Which creates users when I removed the namespacing.

Please note the api code is working perfectly on swagger, when I tried to remove the api versioning the test code works. The issue happened when I namespaced the controller but which is required as I'm building apis. From which file the value of `users_url` is coming?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `rails routes` with each version of the `config/routes.rb`.

You'll notice that when the route is defined in a namespace:

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users
    end 
  end
```

...then the (implicit) route name is actually `api_v1_user_url`, not `user_url`.

I'd advise following that convention, unless you have a clear reason not to. (Convention over configuration is at the heart of ruby on rails' philosophy!)

But if you do want to name the route explicitly, [this can be done with the `as:` parameter](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#naming-routes):

```
  namespace :api do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, as: :users
    end 
  end
```

Comment: Using `as:` doesn't actually change how routes nested in namespaces work. Rather if you you used `resources :users, as: :foos` you still get `api_v1_foos`. If you really wanted to do this you use `scope path: '/api', module: :api do ...` which doesn't nest the route helpers. Mounting the routes without the version prefix still defeats the point of having a path based versioned API though -YAGNI.

Comment: Ahh ok sorry, I didn't actually try that myself and just assumed it would work . My point still stands on "just use the conventional `api_v1_` prefixed route if you're planning to nest the resource under an `/api/v1/` namespace"!

Comment: Yeah, that was just a minor point. The rest of the answer is spot on.